# using adb backup/restore?

Tags: android, backup, adb, restore, android-backup-service

I want to use the `adb backup / restore` . I use `adb restore` to restore a backup. But my problem after some delay, the mechanism restore stops. I want my restore do not stop. And if possible it starts automatically and it does not expect a validation for me.
 used `adb back up` to get my backup.ab. Then i use `adb restore backup.ab`

Comment: would this be of any help: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1420351 ? also, i think you must add a password, as it has bugs when you don't use one.

Answer (score 0):

When restoring, you need to enter the password that your phone had *when you made the backup*, because the backup is encrypted. If you don't enter the correct password, `adb restore` will terminate without warning.

Answer (score 0):

```
adb backup -apk -shared -all -f backup.ab
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this command may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this command answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -2):

This might be 2 years too late but if you remember what parameters you used in the backup, use them when doing `adb restore backup.ab`.

Comment: What do you mean? `adb restore` doesn't take any parameters.